# Pass Multiple Parameters to ReportViewer Tool?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I have hunted and hunted and clearly missing a step but can't work out what.  Running reportViewer in visual basic on asp.net, .net framework 3.5.  Using Visual Studio 2010 express, I have a SSRS server where the reports are based.  Each report takes in 5 parameters.  In the SSRS report itself, they are represented as multi-value drop down boxes and at the moment I have the visual basic with only one value per parameter until I can get the actual report working!!

My vb - sensitive data replaced by descriptions:

```
        rptViewLeft.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote
        rptViewLeft.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://ourserver/Reportserver")
        rptViewLeft.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/folder/reportName"
        rptViewLeft.ShowParameterPrompts = False
        rptViewLeft.ShowPrintButton = True
        rptViewLeft.ShowExportControls = True

        Dim areaName As New ReportParameter
        Dim areaSecondNameAs New ReportParameter
        Dim typeName As New ReportParameter
        Dim subTypeName As New ReportParameter
        Dim judgementName As New ReportParameter
        Dim fromDate As New ReportParameter
        Dim toDate As New ReportParameter
        areaName.Name = "areaName"
        areaSecondName.Name = "areaSecondName"
        typeName.Name = "typeName"
        subTypeName.Name = "subTypeName"
        judgementName.Name = "judgementName"
        fromDate.Name = "fromDate"
        toDate.Name = "toDate"
        areaName.Values.Add(drpareaName.SelectedValue)
        areaSecondName.Values.Add(drpareaSecondName.SelectedValue)
        typeName.Values.Add(drptypeName.SelectedValue)
        subTypeName.Values.Add(drpsubTypeName.SelectedValue)
        judgementName.Values.Add(drpjudgementName.SelectedValue)
        fromDate.Values.Add(drpFromDate.SelectedValue)
        toDate.Values.Add(drpToDate.SelectedValue)

        rptViewLeft.ServerReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() areaName)
```

Obviously I'm missing something between my list of parameters and my 'setParameters' bit - please can someone advise what this step is??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised I was missing the array to pass in the parameters.  I was also missing the following line at the top of my VB file:

```
Imports system.collections.generic
```

The array section added after the 'toDate.Values.Add(drpToDate.SelectedValue)' line is:

```
        Dim parameters As New List(Of ReportParameter)
        parameters.Add(areaName)
        parameters.Add(areaSecondName)
        parameters.Add(typeName)
        parameters.Add(subTypeName)
        parameters.Add(judgementName)
        parameters.Add(fromDate)
        parameters.Add(toDate)

        rptViewLeft.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters)
```

It runs fine now.